# OSGi node blank in intellijIDEA 13 Settings

Tags: java, intellij-idea, osgi

I am new to OSGi and intellijIDEA, i am trying to setup OSGi, but when i go to settings in intellijIDEA, the OSGi node is blank.

[image]

see OSGi framework: [not specified]. how do i fix this?
plus, when i run karaf.bat, "karaf.bat server" or felix.jar, i get nothing. The command line window in blank, i see no progress or whatsoever.

[image]

Please help me fix this issue...

Comment: Is there something in the logs?

Comment: I Cleared log and cache, karaf is working now, but felix is still the same....

Comment: Nevermind, both are working now, thx for the clue :)